# Array - StripTags

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, php-5.6, strip-tags

I have cities in my mysql table. I am getting those through an mysql query. Then I want to display in json format. However, json doesn't display due to not valid characters in the city names. Can anyone help on this? here is my code. I want to get json format somehow by using strip_tags or anything with this array. please help on this guys.

```
$zone = $mcon->query("SELECT name from tbl_cities ORDER BY name ASC");
$data = array();
while ($value = $zone->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $value;
}
echo json_encode(array("text" => $data));
```

Comment: *"However, json doesn't display due to not valid characters in the city names"* That code will correctly create JSON. So it's how you're using that JSON which is the problem, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I need to use strip_tags to avoid characters from city names.. city names are not like Colombo. Sometimes Mazar-e-Sharif, Ech-Chleff (el-Asnam). So I don't know what to strip and what json does not accept. I however know json doesn't accept &quotes. Please help me

Comment: *"I don't know what to strip and what json does not accept"* JSON supports the full range of Unicode characters, which basically means there are no characters JSON doesn't accept. `json_encode` handles outputting correct JSON. You certainly don't want to use `strip_tags` on JSON (but since you haven't shown any use of `strip_tags` above, it's hard to see how `strip_tags` has anything to do with your question).

Comment: there are more than 4000 cities in this mysql. when I am getting 20 cities from same query it displays. what's the fault then ? :)

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Replace( `name` , '-', ' ' ) from tbl_cities ORDER BY name ASC

This will replace all occurances of hyphens with spaces.  There are many functions built into SQL to format the data before you pass it json.

I hope this helps.